# In the term "spacetime" does space mean "distance"?

Tags: spacetime, time

In the term "spacetime" does space mean "distance"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacetime is a 4-dimensional mathematical structure, similarly to how 3-dimensional Euclidian space is a mathematical structure. An event in spacetime is a particular point at $(x,y,z,t)$.

You can define a distance between two points in spacetime. To measure or calculate a distance between two objects, you need to know the location of the two objects at a specific time (i.e. both events have to be well-defined in the four descriptors of spacetime: x, y, z, and t).

Comment: Ok, so it's location-time, not distance-time.